# Can you stop hyphens in Outlook emails?

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, hyphenation

I am developing an email template. The words break to two lines with hyphens when viewed in Outlook emails. I tried a lot of different css properties on the 'td' tag but it's not doing anything.

Is this not possible at all to control?

```
  <tr>
     <td align="center" 
         style="text-transform: initial;
         letter-spacing: 0;
         font-size:40px;
         line-height: 48px;
         font-weight: 700;
         -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
         mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
         word-break: break-word;
         -webkit-hyphens: none;
         -moz-hyphens: none;
         hyphens: none;
         border-collapse: collapse;">
        <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        </div>
     </td>
  </tr>
  
  <!--This is just a spacer-->
  <tr>
     <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: none; -moz-hyphens: none; hyphens: none; border-collapse: collapse; line-height:20px; font-size:20px" height="20px">&nbsp;
     </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
     <td align="center" 
         style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
         mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
         word-break: break-word;
         -webkit-hyphens: none;
         -moz-hyphens: none;
         hyphens: none;
         border-collapse: collapse;
         line-height: 30px; 
         letter-spacing:0.02em;
         font-size:17px;
         line-height:30px;">
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
     </td>
  </tr>
```

[image: works breaking]

[image: words not breaking]

Answer (score 1):

There was a modifier I got from a source that had this piece:
w:AutoHyphenation
I took it out.

Comment: It is cool that you've found where `hyphen` is set!:)

Answer (score 0):

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens) about hyphens:

> Words are not broken at line breaks, even if characters inside the
> words suggest line break points. Lines will only wrap at whitespace.

So you can create a class `no-hyphens` and use it:

```
.no-hyphens {
    hyphens: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion applies to the whole paragraph and keeps it all in one line. I need to fix words breaking in the middle.

Comment: @pitzki it is really hard to say without code. Could you post code and image of what result should be achieved?

Comment: @pitzki and what is desired result?

Comment: The image in the bottom that doesn't have hyphens.

Comment: My inline code has hyphens:none but it does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Add `mso-hyphenate: none;` That should fix the hyphenation problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my  tags for all my emails and it seems to work:

```
      * {
        word-break: keep-all;
        -moz-hyphens: none;
        -ms-hyphens: none;
        -webkit-hyphens: none;
        hyphens: none;
      }
```